# What is the simplest way to find files modified within the past hour?

Tags: perl, find

This question is a special case of
"in perl, what is the simplest way to find files modified within a given time interval?"
and the solution below could easily be generalized.
In bash, we can type

```
> find . -mtime -1h
```

but I want to do this in pure perl. The code below does this. It explicitly runs `stat` on each file.

Is there any way that this can be made simpler or more elegant? Granted, this is slower than the bash command; I am not trying to compete with bash for efficiency. I'm just trying to do it purely in perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use strict; use warnings;
use File::Find;
my $invocation_seconds=time;
my $interval_left =  $invocation_seconds - (60 * 60); # one hour ago
my $count_all=0;
my @selected;
find(
    sub
    {
        $count_all++;
        my $mtime_seconds=(stat($_))[9];
        return unless defined $mtime_seconds; # if we edit files while running current script, this can be undef on occasion 
        return unless ($mtime_seconds>$interval_left);
        push@selected,$File::Find::name;
    }
    ,
    '.', # current directory 
);
my $end_seconds=time;
my $totalselected=scalar@selected;
print ($_,"\n",)for@selected;
print $^V; print " <- perl version\n";
print 'selected ',$totalselected, '/',$count_all,' in ',($end_seconds-$invocation_seconds),' seconds',"\n";
```

Answer (score 6):

```perl
use File::Find::Rule qw( );

my $cutoff = time - 60*60;

say for File::Find::Rule->mtime( ">=$cutoff" )->in( "." );
```

Comment: Am I correct in believing that File::Find::Rule does not add functionality, and does not speed up the performance, but rather offers an alternate syntax by which to do exactly the same thing as plain File::Find?

Comment: @JacobWegelin Right. It doesn't help those at all. But it does help everything that matters. Readability, maintainability, reliability, correctness, etc

Answer (score -1):

Following demo sample code utilizes function [stat](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat) to filter out files modified in last hour.

Note: with slight modification the code can be adopted for recursion

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use constant STAMP => time() - 60*60;
use constant MTIME => 9;

my $dir = shift || '.';
my @files;

(stat($_))[MTIME] > STAMP && push @files, $_
    for glob("$dir/*");

say "
Files changes in last hour
--------------------------";
say for @files;
```

Recursive version which reports lookup time

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday tv_interval);

use constant STAMP => time() - 60*60;
use constant MTIME => 9;

my $dir   = shift || '.';

my $start = [gettimeofday];
my $found = lookup($dir);
my $elapsed = tv_interval($start)

say "
Elapsed lookup time: $elapsed seconds";

say "
Files changed in last hour
--------------------------";
say for @$found;

exit 0;

sub lookup {
    my $dir  = shift;
    my $files;

    for my $item ( glob("$dir/*") ) {
        if( -d $item ) {
            my $matched = lookup($item);
            push @$files, $_ for @{$matched};
        }
        next unless (stat($item))[MTIME] > STAMP;
        push @$files, $item if -f $item;
    }

    return $files;
}
```

Comment: 1) That's not recursive. 2) It doesn't mention files whose name start with `.`. 3) It suffers from a code injection bug that can prevent the code from working with normal inputs. 4) That can be simplified using `grep`.

Comment: ok, so now you added a recursive function. 1) It doesn't print newly modified directories. 2) It doesn't mention files whose name start with `.`. 3) It suffers from a code injection bug that can prevent the code from working with normal inputs. 4) Does 3 `stat` calls for each file. (ow!!!) 5) It's not any simpler than the original. (A bit cleaner, sure, but you could have just cleaned up the original.)

Comment: @ikegami -- I do not see that OP mentioned 'newly modified directories' in his question. What would you use instead of `stat` to get `mtime` on a file? (`find` utilizes `fstat` system call) Or there is a system call I do not know about which returns file list based on stamp criteria? It might be that I will learn something new from you how to get `mtime` of file without calling for `fstat`. My understanding of the question is **How to make provided code look better?** -- as OP mentioned __pure perl__ then a valid approach is to avoid usage of external modules.

Comment: [File::stat](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::stat) is nice for symbolic access to `stat` info, btw.

Comment: Without File::stat, the special `_` filehandle is used to cache the last stat call so after the first `-d $item` you can use `stat _` and `-f _` as a small optimization. Maybe `push @$files, @$matched;` too instead of a loop.

Comment: Re "*- I do not see that OP mentioned 'newly modified directories' in his question.*", What do you think `find . -mtime -1h` does?

Comment: Re "*What would you use instead of stat to get mtime on a file?*", **Strawman** I didn't say you shouldn't use `stat`; I said you shouldn't use it three times per file.You should use `stat` once, and use `_` the other two times.

Comment: Re "*y understanding of the question is How to make provided code look better?*", **Strawman** I didn't say you shouldn't make the code look better. I pointed out bugs that you added in the process, and ways you could improve your code so it would look better.

Comment: Re "*as OP mentioned pure perl then a valid approach is to avoid usage of external modules.*", **Strawman** I didn't say anything about the fact that you didn't use modules. And that's not what pure Perl means anyway.

Comment: @ikegami -- If I put in the code `my $dir = '.';` how would you inject code? This is why in description put __demo sample code__. Unfortunately some programmers do not know what happens inside _module_  (under the hood) and by adopting solution you given their code at times so big and so excessive that it puts a wonder on my mind _why do you do it this way? when you can do same with a few lines of code._. Yes, OOP is very convenient when it makes sense but not at time when the problem is over very simple.

Comment: @PolarBear A far more accepted idiom is to "not re-invent the wheel". Module authors (presumably) spend a lot of time making sure a module does what it is supposed to do in the best way possible. The OP does not ask for efficiency, he asks for simplicity and elegance. He does not ask for code without external modules.